# What to do if one walks out in middle of an Aliya

Tags: halacha, blessing, torah-reading

Recently I was in a Shul where the person who received the Aliya (this was the last Aliya) had an emergency and left in middle of his Aliya. He rushed out so quickly he did not say the Bracha that one makes after the Aliya. There were those who said that the Baal Korai (reader of the Torah) should say it instead of him, and there were others who said that it just gets skipped. What is the halacha in such a case? Does it matter if it is the Kohain or Levi who left?

Comment: very good question at the time of Gemara the first and the last only did bless.  this is at least a proof that the man who bless asking her nosan did not necessarily bless the first bracha.  Kohen and levy are lav davka.  chachomim instituted Kohen and levi because of the darche shslom.  I guess that the baal kore would bless

Comment: Aren't Torah service questions fascinating :-0 ? I'm wondering if on a "fundamental" level, the closing bracha is even necessary? I know that there is a far stronger halacha for the bracha said before starting.